# TikZ: conditional argument

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a macro that draw some objects, which takes as argument an optional parameter (`left` or `right`). To avoid repetitive code, I check for the input argument and condition TikZ parameter on that (`left=of` or `right=of`):

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{left}}{
        \def\side left
    }{
        \def\side right
    }
    \node (A) {$A$}
    \node (B) [\side=of A] {$B$};
```

I obtained the following error:

```
Use of \side doesn't match its definition.
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you want `\def\side{left}`?

Comment: @Symbol1 Oh!! My bad! It works, indeed! Please post an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (simplified) syntax of `\def` is `\def\tokenname#1...{...}`

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{left}}{
        \def\side{left}
    }{
        \def\side{right}
    }
    \node (A) {$A$}
    \node (B) [\side=of A] {$B$};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!